# Немедленно или немедля?

Tags: лексика, падежи

В чем разница между этими наречиями?

Есть предложение: *После смерти супруга Симона **немедля** удалилась в монастырь в Константинополь, где и закончила свои дни.*

Какое наречие лучше подходит?

И дополнительно: *в монастырь **в Константинополь** или в монастырь **в Константинополе**.*

Comment: Кстати наречие немедля произошло от деепричастия не медля. Наречие перед глаголом воспринимается однозначно как характеристика действия. В то время как деепричастие перед глаголом может иметь и другие функции. Таким образом более просто и однозначно текст должен восприниматься с классическим наречием немедленно, чем с наречием-деепричастием немедля.

Comment: Еще я подумал что у нас уже есть одно временное наречие в предложении - после.. с которым второе временное наречие... немедленно вступает в легкий стилевой диссонанс. Не вникая в дополнительную структуру предложения, сразу хочется спросить: так после или немедленно? Один из выходов такой: Сразу после смерти супруга Симона удалилась в монастырь. Второй выход это деепричастие

Comment: По значению это не медля, без промедления, без задержки. Но по правилам написание должно быть слитное. А собственно говоря, почему? Кто и когда так решил?

Comment: А встречаются ли вообще наречия полностью совпадающие по написанию с деепричастиями? Может поэтому и приходится писать слитно, чтобы отличить одно от другого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словарях Ушакова и Ефремовой сказано, что это то же, что *немедленно*. Но в последнем пометка *разг.*, что и мне кажется.

Но в стилистике, на мой взгляд, разница есть. "*Немедленно*" употребляется в контекстах, когда что-то **нужно** сделать (срочно), а "*немедля*" - без замедлений, быстро, сразу же. В этом плане оно больше подходит, хотя звучание самого слова мне не нравится.

Монастырь (*где?*) в Константинополе. Или после "*монастырь*" запятая как уточнение.

Касательно повторения предлогов:
*Он поехал на рынок на рабОту.* || Движение от общего к основному. Читается без паузы.
*Он поехал на рабОту, на рынок.* || Наоборот так уже не получается.

Мне кажется, что всё-таки *Константинополь* общее, а *монастырь* - основное. Но с предлогом В такое звучит хуже, чем с другими.

Comment: oleedd, у на два критерия: смысл и стиль. По смыслу разницу вы обозначили: срочно и без промедления. А стиль? Мне это "немедля" кажется разговорным. А вот в форме  деепричастия оно выглядит нормально. Что вы думаете о стиле?

Comment: Может, о стилистике? Мне тоже кажется разговорным, как уже сказано в ответе. Мне это слово не нравится. Почему? Звучит как небрежное сокращение от *немедленно*. И вот эта субъективность сказывается (на звучании) при анализе стилистики. А вот раздельное "*не медля*" (от *медлить*) звучит хорошо, согласен.

Answer (score 1):

Различие можно усмотреть в том, что наречие "**немедля**" имеет деепричастное происхождение. Это настолько заметно, что привязывает его по смыслу к *действию субъекта* (= не долго думая, что-то *сам* сделал) и даже выражает намек на имевшееся у него *желание*  сделать сказанное (как в примере). "**Немедленно**" может употребляться более широко, например, характеризовать скорость реакции *других* производителей действия на события, связанные с упомянутым субъектом. Пример, когда "**немедля**" не может использоваться вместо "**немедленно**" (в случае такой замены употребление этого слова было бы просторечным):

> Он вышел на шоссе и был *немедленно* сбит машиной.

*По стилю* "немедленно" плохо сочетается с *ретроспективным* повествованием (как в примере из вопроса, где "*немедля*" выглядит уместнее; можно заменить это слово на "*сразу же*", "*тут же*", "*вскоре*" и т. п.), это наречие больше подходит к рассказу о *недавних* событиях, к репортажу (*нарушитель был **немедленно** задержан*). Более формальный его синоним "**незамедлительно**" типичен для инструкций или полицейских отчётов.